# How to apply a cast to all columns matching a regex pattern with Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I'm new to Polars and I'm struggling with something probably easy!

In my dataframe, I have multiple columns named `timeline_abc` with `abc` always different.
These columns contain only Unix timestamp.

I'm able to cast another type doing:

```
df = df.with_columns(
  pl.col("timeline_reco").cast(pl.Datetime("ms")).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y"),
  pl.col("timeline_enco").cast(pl.Datetime("ms")).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y"),
  pl.col("timeline_vico").cast(pl.Datetime("ms")).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y"),
  ...)
```

But because the number of concerned columns is big, it's not DRY at all!

I've tried with `homes_df.select(pl.col('^timeline_.*$'))`, but I can't succeed iterating and applying my cast afterwards.

Any clue?

EDIT:

More precisely, I've tried:

```
homes_df = homes_df.with_columns(pl.col('^timeline_.*$').cast(pl.Datetime("ms")).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```

But it returns an error (see pic).

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `pl.col('^timeline_.*$').cast(...)`?

Comment: Yes but `homes_df = homes_df.with_columns(pl.col('^timeline_.*$').cast(pl.Datetime("ms")).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))` returns an error `ComputeError: cannot cast List type (inner: 'Null', to: 'Datetime(Milliseconds, None)')` (I'm going to edit the question)

Comment: That error is saying one of the columns matching the regex is of type `list[null]` (and not `str` as expected)

Answer (score 1):

You can use selectors to ensure you're only picking the columns that are also strings

https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#examples

```
import polars.selectors as cs

df.with_columns(
    (cs.string() & cs.matches("timeline_")).cast(pl.Datetime("ms")).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
)
```

or if it's just one issue use `exclude`

```
homes_df.with_columns(pl.col('^timeline_.*$').exclude(pl.List).cast(pl.Datetime("ms")).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```